# Deleted /usr/bin/env by mistake, how can I recover it?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, data-recovery

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 X64, I deleted my `/usr/bin/env` file by mistake. How could I restore this?

Also I copy a file as `/usr/bin/dev`, I don't know if I originally had a file called `/usr/bin/dev`. If so, how could I restore this as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `/usr/bin/env` file originates from the `coreutils` package. To restore it, simply reinstall this package. In order to do so, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

There is currently no package in Ubuntu repositories which provides a `/usr/bin/dev` file. Therefore you don't need to restore it.

Comment: Thanks... it worked in Centos 7 as well with:
# yum reinstall coreutils

Answer (score 1):

you can have the file back by asking for people who have the same architecture as yours ( not including me:( ) to give you the same file. then you must put it back as user `root` and give it permission `755`.

I don't have any file on my freshly installed Ubuntu as `/usr/bin/dev` ;)

Comment: Manually placing a very essential binary file in your system may be *very* dangerous, avoid this unless you trust the file's source fully! Also, it may lead to significant problems in case you mistakenly use another (either newer or older) version of this file that you deleted.